# Can't install apache on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: apache2, mysql

I have apache files downloaded, and I've not been able to install the, it keeps listing dependencies and when I check my list of installed packages, it lists apache2 as deinstall, I equally have not been able to run mysql either. What should I do, because the system is not connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

[Download](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html#download):

```
$ lynx http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi
```

[Extract](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html#extract):

```
$ gzip -d httpd-NN.tar.gz
$ tar xvf httpd-NN.tar
$ cd httpd-NN
```

[Configure](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html#configure):

```
$ ./configure --prefix=PREFIX
```

[Compile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html#compile):

```
$ make
```

[Install](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html#install):

```
$ make install
```

[Customize](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html#customize):

```
$ vi PREFIX/conf/httpd.conf
```

[Test](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html#test):

```
$ PREFIX/bin/apachectl -k start
```

Comment: I've done just that but it stops with an error APR not found @Radu

Comment: @pamodulus Can you edit your question by posting the error?

Comment: I was able to pack multiple downloaded .deb packages and ran " sudo dpkg -i *.*" most things including apache, PHP and MySQL installed, I was even prompted to give a password for my root MySQL account, but after the apache on /var/php5/apache2 ran, it doesn't recognise localhost and I can't start MySQL without geting the error " can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) ", and the file path doesn't even exist on my machine @Radu